# How to call remote method of one persisted model inside another remote method of another persisted model

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

here's what I tried in model1.js:

```
      model1.remotemethod1 = function(id, data, cb) {
var model2 = app.models.model2;
model2.remotemethod2(id, data).then(response => {
cb(null, true);
});
 };
```

this is my model2.js : 
it has the definition of remotemethod2 .

```
 'use strict';

  module.exports = function(model2) {

  model2.remotemethod2 = function(id, data, cb) {
     var promise;
     let tags = data.tags ? data.tags.slice() : [];
     delete data.categories;
     delete data.tags;
     promise = model2.upsertWithWhere({
             or: [
                 {barcode: data.barcode},
                 {id: data.id},
             ],
         }, data);
     promise.then(function(model2) {
         model2.tags.destroyAll().then(function() {
             for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                 model2.tags.add(tags[i]);
             }
             cb(null, model2);
         });
     });
    };
 };
```

But it dos not work ! 
I think that  app.models.model2 does not give me the model with its remote methods !  maybe I should get an instance of the model2 !

Comment: Can you share your error message and the code for the remote methods?

Comment: I just shared the remotemethod1 code ! the second isn't important ! 
and the error message is  :  "model2.remotemethod2 doesn't exit "

Comment: Are you sure the remote method exists, can you see it in the loopback explorer?

Comment: Yes it exist (even if I don't need it there ) .. all I want is to call it from another remote method . I think I have the wrong syntax ! the main question is how remote methods are called outside the model .

Comment: This would be easier with your model2.js.  You're calling it in the correct way, but it apparently doesn't exist.  You're also passing a callback and expecting a promise at the same time, which is a bit odd

Comment: I shared the model2.js !

Comment: @ghassenlassoued how are you calling app ? for `app.models.model2;`

Comment: @AnouarKacem  this way  : var app = require('../server');

Comment: I have no problem with app ! I used it before  (different from calling remote methods ) and it works fine

Comment: I think the main problem is that  app.models.yourmodel does not have  your remote method. in that way  we cant do app.models.yourmodel.yourremotemethod.

Comment: Can you share `console.log(model2)?`

Comment: function model2(data, options) {
        if (!(this instanceof model2)) {
          return new model2(data, options);
        }
        if (model2.settings.unresolved) {
          throw new Error(g.f('Model %s is not defined.', "model2"));
        }
        ModelBaseClass.apply(this, arguments);
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var (VAR-NAME)= (CURRENT-MODEL).app.models.(ANOTHER_MODEL);
```

you now can use the other model by calling one of its methods for example

EX:

```
VAR-NAME.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `remotemethod1` in `server.js` `app.start` and you'll have access to the correct `app.models.model2` and you will be able to use its remote method.

```
app.start = function() {
     model1.remotemethod1 = (id, data, cb) =>  {
        var model2 = app.models.model2;
        model2.remotemethod2(id, data).then(response => {
           cb(null, true);
        });
     };

      model1.remoteMethod(
        'remotemethod1', {
            http: { path: '/remotemethod1', verb: 'post', status: 200, errorStatus: 400 },
            accepts: [{arg: 'id', type: 'number'}, {arg: 'id', type: 'object'}],
            returns: {arg: 'status', type : 'string' }
        }) ;
    }  

    //  The rest of app.start...
```

EDIT you can also create the remote method will the correct `app` context with a file located in `myprojectname/server/boot`

```
`module.exports(app) {
     /* Create remote methods here */
}`
```

Comment: I could have done the job of remotemethod2  inside the first remotemethod1 ! I just wanted the code that belongs to model2 to be done (written) inside model2.js !  so  taking the remotemethod1 to server.js  is the same for me as writing  all the code inside model1 !

Comment: I agree it's not ideal, but it does answer the question as asked.